# How to use typescript with dynamic object key

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a State object that records time in days, hours, and minutes. I defined my state like this:

```
type StateKeys = "days" | "hours" | "minutes";

type State = {
    [K in StateKeys]: number
};
```

Later, I want to set state based on a value changed in a control.  There are three controls, one for day, another for hours, and a third for minutes.  I have one handler function that is hooked up to each of these controls.  Here's an excerpt of that function:

```
_onTimeComponentChange(e: any) {
    const name : StateKeys = e.currentTarget.name;
    const updatedValue = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value);
    this.setState(
        //@ts-ignore
        {[name]: updatedValue}, 
        () => {
            this.updateValue();
        }
    )
}
```

My goal is to remove the `//@tsignore` comment.  If I do that now, I get this error message:

> Argument of type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'State | ((prevState: Readonly, props:
>   Readonly) => State | Pick) | Pick'.   Type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is missing the
>   following properties from type 'Pick': days, hours,
>   minutes

How do I remove the `//@tsignore`comment and satisfy typescript's requirements?

Comment: Typescript does not do well with computed properties if the type computed property type is a union. I sometimes just pick one member and use a type assertion `const name = e.currentTarget.name as "days";` looks dumb .. but it is what it is ..

Comment: Thanks @TitianCernicova-Dragomir.  It definitely feels like black magic to me trying to satisfy Typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely hard to get around this type of thing without casting. You can try following the pattern described [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635#issuecomment-400260278):

```
updateState(key: StateKeys, value: string) {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [key]: value,
  }));
}
```

which would look like:

```
_onTimeComponentChange(e: any) {
  const name: StateKeys  = e.currentTarget.name
  const updatedValue = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value)
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: updatedValue,
    }),
    () => {
    },
  )
}
```